# combobox binding MVVM C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, binding

Im missing something but i have no idea what :(

I've bind IEnumerable collection to combobox. I would like to use its selected value as parameter for shutdown command, however when i press start button it doesn't load selected values.

I've followed few tutorials to understand MVVM but there is still something missing but i cant figured out what.

Here is MainWindow.xaml :

```
<grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <!--Title label-->
        <TextBlock Text="Wyłącz komputer za:" Margin="5"/>

        <!-- Blocks used to set hours and minutes-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Godziny:" Margin="5"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="HoursCB" Margin="5" Width="40" ItemsSource="{Binding myHours}" SelectedValue="{Binding selectedHours, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <TextBlock Text="Minuty:" Margin="5" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="MinutesCB" Margin="5" Width="40" ItemsSource="{Binding myMinutes}" SelectedValue="{Binding selectedMinutes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </StackPanel >

        <!-- Timer -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label x:Name="HHLabel" Content="{Binding selectedHours}" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="45"/>
            <Label x:Name="Colon1" Content=":" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="25"/>
            <Label x:Name="MMLabel" Content="{Binding selectedMinutes}" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="45"/>
            <Label x:Name="Colon2" Content=":" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="25"/>
            <Label x:Name="SSLabel" Content="00" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="45"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Start Button -->
        <Button Content="uruchom odliczanie" Margin="5" Command="{Binding StartCommand}" />

        <!-- Stop Button-->
        <Button Content="Zatrzymaj odliczanie" Margin="5" Command="{Binding StopCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</grid>
```

and here is view model :

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        StartCommand = new AddNameCommand(this);
    }

    class AddNameCommand : ICommand
    {
        MainWindowViewModel parent;

        public AddNameCommand(MainWindowViewModel parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
            parent.PropertyChanged += delegate { CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); };
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        { return true; }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            int num = parent.SelectedHours * 3600 + parent.SelectedMinutes * 60;
            MessageBox.Show($"Shutting down the computer in {num} !");
            //Process.Start("shutdown", string.Format("/s /t {0}", num));
        }
    }

    public ICommand StartCommand { get; private set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Combobox Items.
    /// </summary>
    //public IEnumerable<int> myHours = Enumerable.Range(0, 23);
    //public IEnumerable<int> myMinutes = Enumerable.Range(1, 59);
    public ObservableCollection<int> myHours { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 23));
    public ObservableCollection<int> myMinutes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 59));


    /// <summary>
    /// Selected time properties.
    /// </summary>
    public int SelectedMinutes
    {
        get { return mSelectedMinutes; }
        set
        {
            if (value == mSelectedMinutes)
                return;
            mSelectedMinutes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    int mSelectedMinutes;

    public int SelectedHours
    {
        get { return mSelectedHours; }
        set
        {
            if (value == mSelectedHours)
                return;
            mSelectedHours = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    int mSelectedHours;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }
}
```

Comment: Is the combobox populated correctly? are facing issues only in `SelectedValue`

Comment: yes. from some reason there is 22 hours instead of 23 but rest is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `xaml` to the following (note the case sensitive **S**electedHours/Minutes):

```
    <!-- Blocks used to set hours and minutes-->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Godziny:" Margin="5"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="HoursCB" Margin="5" Width="40" ItemsSource="{Binding myHours}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedHours, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBlock Text="Minuty:" Margin="5" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="MinutesCB" Margin="5" Width="40" ItemsSource="{Binding myMinutes}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMinutes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel >
```

Binding errors can be easily detected by opening the `Output Window` in `Visual Studio` and looking for the following:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'selectedHours' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=46431654)'. BindingExpression:Path=selectedHours; DataItem='MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=46431654); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='HoursCB'); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object')
```

Comment: Hahaha !!! Thats the one :) thanks for advice with this output window :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not binded the Selected Values of combo boxes to the right property in the View Model. Just change "selectedHours" to "SelectedHours" and "selectedMinutes" to "SelectedMinutes" in your XAML to bind it properly.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

You code is behaving like i expedted it. Your problem is the [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) function. It starts with an inclusive 0 and then counts up 23 times Inclunding 0

Comment: Well it explain why I have only 22 hours in combobox but the biggest problem is not workingshutdown command

Comment: I dont see any shutdown command in your code. Only Start and Stop. Do you mean the AddName/Start command?

Comment: Start button supposed to run start command, which should run commented line in execute method whith values taken from comboboxes however when I run this line it instantly shutdown computer

Comment: I simmulate shutdown command with MessageBox but it says "Shutting down in 0"